# Import a MIDI, then modify and export as a tracker module on Linux

Tags: linux, media-converter, music-production, midi, music-composing

I want to compose a [tracker module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_file), but not from scratch.  I have public-domain MIDI file that I want to derive my work from, but I'm struggling to find a workflow that fits these requirements:

- The program(s) must run on Linux.
- The melody and structure of an imported MIDI must be preserved.

  - To clarify what I mean by this: I should be able to import my MIDI, play it without modifications, and be able to recognize the song.
- I must be able to provide my own samples as WAV files.
- I must be able to modify the imported music as I see fit.
- I must be able to export a module in any one of the major formats (IT, S3M, MOD, or XM).

Some notes:

- [schismtracker](http://schismtracker.org) is not an option, because the MIDI import is [too buggy](https://github.com/schismtracker/schismtracker/issues/190).
- I don't need to export back to a MIDI file.
- I'm not looking to strictly *convert*, I'm looking to *adapt*.  So it's okay if I need to run my MIDI through a chain of converters, as long as the info I need is preserved.
- It's okay if these aforementioned converters are command-line programs, but they still have to run on Linux.
- I don't know much about how MIDI works; I know that it's a file format, but apparently it's an input device too?  It's okay if I have to jury-rig something, but I need to know what that something should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having done some research, I went with [OpenMPT](https://openmpt.org).  It fits all of my requirements to a T.  While it's a Windows program, it *does* run very well on WINE; that's even one of its selling points.  It was simple to set up the 64-bit version.  Just remember that you may have to map MIDI instruments to samples before you can hear anything.